# Select columns in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

Assumes there is an index and a matrix L

```
>>> index
(array([0, 2, 3, 3]), array([0, 2, 2, 3]))
>>> L
array([[  1,  -1,  -5, -10],
   [-15,   0,  -1,  -5],
   [-10, -15,  10,  -1],
   [ -5, -10,   1,  15]])
```

I want to select the columns according to the index[1], I've tried:

```
>>> L[:,index[1]]
array([[  1,  -5,  -5, -10],
   [-15,  -1,  -1,  -5],
   [-10,  10,  10,  -1],
   [ -5,   1,   1,  15]])
```

but the result is not i expected, what I expected is:

```
>>> for i in index[1]:
...     print L[:,i]
[  1 -15 -10  -5]
[-5 -1 10  1]
[-5 -1 10  1]
[-10  -5  -1  15]
```

How can i get the expected result without for loop? and why this unexpected result comes out? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to [*transpose*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) it:

```
L[:,index[1]].T
#             ^ transpose
```

By using a transpose, the columns are rows and vice versa. So here (you can transpose before the selection, and then use `L.T[index[1],:]`) we first make the selection and then turn the columns into rows.

This produces:

```
>>> L[:,index[1]].T
array([[  1, -15, -10,  -5],
       [ -5,  -1,  10,   1],
       [ -5,  -1,  10,   1],
       [-10,  -5,  -1,  15]])
```

Note that of course behind the curtains there are still some loops that are done. But these are done outside Python and thus are more efficient.